# Footnotes are only appearing after a manual text box shift. Help!

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got a terrifying InDesign bug and I'm hoping someone else has come across it/knows how to avoid it.

This never happened before InDesign 2018 (v14), but it's been happening since. Sometimes footnotes just *won't appear* until you tug at the text box, thereby revealing them. It isn't a one-time occurrence either. Any change to the document might result in some footnotes hiding themselves again.

I've included an example from a journal I work on.

[image: Indesign footnote disappearance bug]

Comment: I think you'll need to contact Adobe about this one.

Comment: InDesign does stuff like this sometimes. Sadly, it's not as stable as one could wish. Could be a general bug or just a bug in your current document.